# Set password after google authentication in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel-5

I am trying to implement google login using socialite plugin in laravel in which I want to set password filed (is user should set a new password before entering into the profile page).

After the password entering I need to create  a new user entry via `User::create()` method ,but I don't know how to access the `$user` variable in my createUser function

**Code**

```
public funtion handleCallback($provider) {
    //get userinfo
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    //set new password  
    return view('views.new-password');
}

//new password and create user
public function createUser(Request $request) {
    //$user from handleCallback 
    dd($user)
}
```

Can I use a session variable to store this data so that I can access across multiple controllers is it the right way to do this??